# C# How do you add a column to an existing datatable for each data row by Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a CSV file that I have read into a DataTable.  I had to grab and concatenate certain field values for each "Member ID".  I created a LINQ query for that and have the data I need and the "Member ID".

What I am struggling with is joining the two data sets together and either creating a new column in the DataTable or creating a new DataTable from the join.

```
DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);


var query =
    from data in csvData.AsEnumerable()
    group data by data.Field<string>("MEMBER ID") into g
    select new
    {
        MemberId = g.Key,
        Reason1 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON1") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION1")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason2 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON2") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION2")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason3 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON3") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION3")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason4 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON4") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION4")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason5 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON5") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION5")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason6 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON6") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION6")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason7 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON7") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION7")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason8 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON8") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION8")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason9 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON9") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION9")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason10 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON10") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("CLAIM HEADER REASON DESCRIPTION10")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason11 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON1") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON DESCRIPTION1")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason12 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON2") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON DESCRIPTION2")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason13 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON3") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON DESCRIPTION3")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason14 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON4") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON DESCRIPTION4")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason15 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON5") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON DESCRIPTION5")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault(),
        Reason16 = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON6") + "-  " + x.Field<string>("LINE ITEM REASON DESCRIPTION6")).Where(y => y != "-  ").Distinct().FirstOrDefault()
    };

var results =
    from r in query
    select new
    {
        MemberId = r.MemberId,
        Reason = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason1) ? string.Empty : r.Reason1.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason2) ? string.Empty : r.Reason2.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason3) ? string.Empty : r.Reason3.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason4) ? string.Empty : r.Reason4.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason5) ? string.Empty : r.Reason5.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason6) ? string.Empty : r.Reason6.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason7) ? string.Empty : r.Reason7.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason8) ? string.Empty : r.Reason8.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason9) ? string.Empty : r.Reason9.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason10) ? string.Empty : r.Reason10.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason11) ? string.Empty : r.Reason11.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason12) ? string.Empty : r.Reason12.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason13) ? string.Empty : r.Reason13.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason14) ? string.Empty : r.Reason14.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason15) ? string.Empty : r.Reason15.Trim() + "|!|",
                               string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Reason16) ? string.Empty : r.Reason16.Trim() + "|!|")
    };
```

This part is good.  I have what I need.  The following code is where I am struggling.

```
var output =
    from r in results.AsEnumerable()
    join c in csvData.AsEnumerable()
        on r.MemberId equals c.Field<string>("MEMBER ID")
    select new
    {
        c,
        r.Reason
    };
```

In my output I am getting "System.Data.DataRow,MyConcatenatedData"

I know it's got to be something stupidly easy but I am running on little sleep so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the output

> System.Data.DataRow

Because in the select query, you have selected the object `c` and not its fields. Your query should be .

```
var output =
    from r in results.AsEnumerable()
    join c in csvData.AsEnumerable()
        on r.MemberId equals c.Field<string>("MEMBER ID")
    select new
    {
        c.Field1FromcsvData,
        c.Field2FromcsvData,
        r.Reason
    };
```

Comment: That's what I am doing now.  I was hoping there was an equivalent of * as there are over 200 of the fields.